# Seder HaAvoda "Ata Konanta" in Nusach Ashkenaz

Tags: prayer-book, yom-kippur, nusach-ashkenaz

Which Nusach Ashkenaz communities/shuls say in Mussaf Yom Kippur the Seder HaAvoda that starts with "Ata Konantah"?

The standard Seder haAvodah in Nusach Ashekenaz is the piyut Amitz Koach. In Nusach Sefaradim/Edot haMizrach, and in Nusach Sfard it is the piyut Ata Konantah. However, both the Artscroll Machzor and Daniel Goldschmidt's Machzor note that a minority of Nusach Ashkenaz communities switched to Ata Konantah (DG notes that this was a very late development). Which communities did or do follows such custom?

Answer (score 2):

The משכן שילה synagogue in the רמת שילה neighborhood of בית שמש, Israel. (Source: The גבאי told me.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113014/discussion-on-answer-by-msh210-seder-haavoda-ata-konanta-in-nusach-ashkenaz).